# Washing up and status of a cooking pot

Tags: halacha, kashrut-kosher

If a kosher pot is washed up with cold water and washing up liquid, and a washing up pad that has been used to wash non-kosher pots - what is the status of the pot?

Comment: Hi SAF and welcome to Mi Yodeya! Please consider taking our [tour] where you can see some useful information about the site. Be aware that we don’t accept halachic inquiries on this site - if you’re asking out of curiosity, please, go ahead, but if you’re asking for a practical matter, you should ask a competent, knowledgeable Rabbi that you know personally, rather than a bunch of Internet strangers. Regardless, thank you for bringing this intriguing question to our attention, and I hope to see you around.

Answer (score 2):

The classical case is one of washing a dairy pot with a meat sponge or vice versa. If the pot and cleaning water are cold, the pot is fine (but needs to be cleaned well with an appropriate sponge) and the sponge should be thrown away (as it is too difficult to clean). See sources below.

I do not see how a sponge being used with non-kosher pots would be different. But, as with anything else on this site, you should [consult your rabbi](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/9146)
before implementing anything [you learn here](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1734).

---

din.org [writes](http://dinonline.org/2017/02/26/milichig-sponge-on-fleishig-pot/)

> If the pot had actually fleishig on it, then the sponge should be
>   thrown out because it is too hard to clean. If it was a clean pot and
>   it was only used for pareve, then the sponge is alright.
>
> Regarding the pot: If it was washed with cold water or even warm
>   water, that wasn’t yad soledes bo, 110 F, then it is fine. Just wash
>   it off with soap to get off anything the sponge might have left on it,
>   and it is alright.

Halachafortoday [writes](https://halachafortodaycom.blogspot.com/2013/02/archives-hilchos-kashrus.html) (under Jan 14, 2010)

> If one class of dishes was mistakenly washed with a sponge of the
>   other class, in most cases the dishes do not become non Kosher, as the
>   water is usually not hot enough. However, the utensil should
>   immediately be re-rinsed with cold water and with the proper cleaning
>   apparatus. If the dish in question is glass, there is room for even
>   more leniency. As always, whenever in doubt, a Rav must be consulted.

For more see also [EretzHemda](http://www.eretzhemdah.org/qna.asp?lang=en&pageid=&cat=17) ("Dairy ingredients prepared in a pareve bowl") and [AskRevach](http://revach.net/ask/article.php?id=987#comments).